# can't add external js script to javascript Evaluator in streamsets

Tags: streamsets

I am using external javascript inside javascript evaluator in streamsets. But when i try to load the external code i got following error. How should i resolve this. Thanks

> ERROR SafeScheduledExecutorService - Uncaught throwable from
>   com.streamsets.pipeline.lib.executor.SafeScheduledExecutorService$SafeCallable@69717812:
>   com.streamsets.datacollector.util.PipelineException: PREVIEW_0003 -
>   Encountered error while previewing :
>   java.security.AccessControlException: access denied
>   ("java.io.FilePermission"
>   "/opt/streamsets-datacollector-user-libs/test.js" "read")
>   com.streamsets.datacollector.util.PipelineException: PREVIEW_0003 -
>   Encountered error while previewing :
>   java.security.AccessControlException: access denied
>   ("java.io.FilePermission"
>   "/opt/streamsets-datacollector-user-libs/test.js" "read")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I've responded [elsewhere](https://ask.streamsets.com/question/2810/cant-add-external-js-script-to-javascript-evaluator/?answer=2811#post-id-2811), you will need to add a security policy to be able to load a script file. Add the following to `$SDC_CONF/sdc-security.policy` :

```
// Set global perm so that JS can load scripts from this directory
// Note - this means any code in the JVM can read this dir!
grant {
  permission java.io.FilePermission "/opt/streamsets-datacollector-user-libs/-", "read";
};
```

You will need to restart Data Collector for changes to the security policy file to take effect.

Comment: By default policy file have the following line 

`// custom stage library directory
grant codebase "file:///opt/streamsets-datacollector-user-libs/-" {
  permission java.security.AllPermission;
};`
That means if I add the required file inside that directory. Should the file load in my js evaluator processor without reloading ??

Comment: That's a different permission - that is saying that code loaded from `/opt/streamsets-datacollector-user-libs` can do anything. This is different from the permission I described, which says that any code can load files from `/opt/streamsets-datacollector-user-libs`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification

Comment: Use this code block if you want to use HTTP call inside your javascript evaluator. 
[https://gist.github.com/billybong/a462152889b6616deb02](https://gist.github.com/billybong/a462152889b6616deb02)